# Adware keeps installing itself

Tags: security, malware

I have somehow got my phone infected with an adware by the name *'Android Communication Sync'* ('com.foreign.provider').

It isn't visible in the apps browser (doesn't have any icon) and causes ads to occassionally display out of nowhere.

I have tried to uninstall it multiple times, but everytime I find it installed on my phone after a few days (it appears in *Settings -> Apps -> Downloaded*).

My current solution is to disable (freeze) it, so that it atleast doesn't disturb with me ads.

How can I remove it and prevent it from getting installed again?

My phone is a rooted Micromax Unite 2 (Micromax A106) running Android 4.4.2. As far as I remember, I haven't installed any app outside of Google Play Store except [Adaway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway).

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YIE95LK_V4OGVBcmY2VU8tMTA/view?usp=sharing) is its apk I exported using Link2SD.

Comment: It could be that some other app you installed might be installing this app as an add-on. So no matter how many times you force remove it, as long as the "mother" app is there, it will still re-download it. That's one theory. Try uninstalling those recent apps that you might've installed one at a time to narrow down on the culprit.

Comment: @blueren Is it possible for an app hosted on the Play Store to do such thing? Doesn't Google filter these kinds of malware out?

Comment: You never know. Something similar came up [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/4n86x2/android_communication_sync_apps_a_virus/). Not entirely informative though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for adware, as well as other "viruses" to be installed on the sd card. Thus even doing a factory reset can reinstall the "virus". If you have access to a pc with virus protection on it. You can mount the phone as a USB storage and scan it from there. Besides wiping both the phone and the sd card. There may not be a permanent fix. But if you are able to locate the file and delete it from there. That may fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Root your device and remove the file

'/system/bin/fotabinder' using root explorer.

Then uninstall the App Android Communication sync. This would break your OTA updates though.

Recommend you to update your firmware or Flash with a new ROM